# Check delimiter ,(comma) in a text file with inconsistent columns and add data to Excel in Python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, csv

I have a number of text files with delimiter `,` as below.

Example of a text file:

```
a,
b,
c,
a,d,b,
k,m,
f,g,h,j,
```

I need output in an Excel file with each text file in different worksheet. I am getting a parser error when `pd.read_table` encounters inconsistent size in columns, such as in line 4 of text file, where it says expected 2 fields saw 4.

```
a
b
c
a d b
k m
f g h j
```

I am using below code:

```
df = pd.read_table("exp.txt",delimiter = ",", header=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from the fact that you have a non fixed number of fields.

I see two options. Either you know in advance the number of columns (or at least an upper bound) and you can specify the columns:

```
N_COLs = 10
df = (pd.read_csv(your_file, sep=',', names=range(N_COLs))
        .dropna(how='all', axis=1) # optional, to drop empty columns
     )
```

Or you don't and you could pass a dummy non-existent separator to have a single column, then `split`:

```
df = (pd.read_csv(your_file, sep='--NOSEP--', header=None, engine='python')[0]
        .str.strip(', ').str.split(',', expand=True)
     )
```

*NB. the second approach wouldn't be able to correctly parse CSV if you have quoted fields, this only works with a simple `,` separator.*

Output:

```
   0     1     2     3
0  a  None  None  None
1  b  None  None  None
2  c  None  None  None
3  a     d     b  None
4  k     m  None  None
5  f     g     h     j
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of variable columns lengths in each line. Can fix the number of maximum cols to fixed value. Try below example

```
import pandas as pd

number_of_max_cols = 4
cols_name = ["co1" + str(i+1) for i in range(number_of_max_cols)]
df = pd.read_table("pl_file.txt",delimiter = ",", names=cols_name, header=None)
print(df)
```

output :

```
  co11 co12 co13 co14
0    a  NaN  NaN  NaN
1    b  NaN  NaN  NaN
2    c  NaN  NaN  NaN
3    a    d    b  NaN
4    k    m  NaN  NaN
5    f    g    h    j
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as [I already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78165989)